# Получить данные об отправленном сообщении в Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram, callback

Хочу записать в БД id сообщения и чата(группы/канала). Какими способами можно получить эти данные из сообщения, которое отправляет бот, с тем условием, что сообщение отправляется без использования пользовательских команд? Может используется какая-нибудь callback функция, которую можно вызвать после отправки сообщения, чтобы бот обратно получил эти данные?

Пишу на php с использованием библиотеки https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core